# How to return to the same activity instance after resuming it?

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume, activity-lifecycle

The problem is somewhat odd and after having trying to figure it out for about a day now, I am posting it here. 
I have an application where an activity A(main activity) launches other activities(B,C or D). 
The issue here happens when activity A has started Activity B and 'home' button is pressed.

Case 1 - When I test my application in debug mode on my device (HTC Desire) after pressing the 'home' button, I again click the application icon, it returns to the same activity (activity B), which is what is should do. No issues here.

Case 2 - When I export the signed package, and then install the application on the same device, then if I click the application icon after pressing the 'home' button, then a new instance of activity A (main activity) is launched ON TOP of activity B. I got to know this because when I press 'back' from that activity, it returns to activity B and pressing 'back' again shown activity A.

The behavior ceases to exist if the application is quit in the same order it was started, that is, if I press 'back' from activity B, then 'back' from activity A (exit).

After this everything runs fine. 
I have tested it many times with different settings but I can't seem to figure out why the behavior is like this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: just put the logcat for both before signed & after signed apk.

Comment: logcat isnt helping in this case, no errors are there.

Comment: the behavior is A launches B --> click 'home' --> click app launcher --> A is again pushed on the app stack which now is A -> B -> A. A is the root activity.

Comment: OOOK...after banging my head for some more hours and after trying all possible permutations possible, I figured it out. I am using android 2.2 and its a bug in the apk installer. I tried it on 5 apps, all giving same result.
1-- take any apk from ur sdcard and install it
2-- after the installation is complete, Open the app from the screen which shows the 'installaion complete' message.
3-- Now press the 'home' button to put the application in background
4-- Go to the application's icon and open it from there.
Now u can repeat the same process to open as many instances as possible, repetitively

Comment: did u find any solution for this, same thing happens when i run my application in kindle(2.3 version) through eclipse. On other devices its working good with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think giving Activity A the 'single top' flag in your manifest should fix this.

Comment: Making activity A singleTop won't help. It might help to making activity B singleTop. But by default you don't need it, it should return existing stack to the screen. Are all your activities settings set by default?

Comment: I did try to make activity A singleTop but it didnt help.
@damluar: yes, all the activities settings are set as default

Comment: singleTop is only for secondary Activities. It's to ensure that you don't launch a second copy of whatever you are bringing to the front (ie. the top of stack). Top is not the start activity of the app, it is the currently viewed one.

Comment: did I misunderstand the question? User doesn't want a second instance of Activity A being launched right?

Comment: yes, i dont want a second instance, but as i have pointed out its an issue with apk installer. I have posted the behavior here -> [link]http://www.devashish.co.in/2011/06/android-2-2-apk-installer-issue/  Please let me know if anyone is able to replicate this

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Case 1:
When launching your intent from Activity A to start Activity B, add the flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET)
This will ensure that when you go home and launch the the app again, Activity A will be shown.

Regarding Case 2:
I'm not exactly sure how this would occur. It seems like it thinks you have two versions of the app, the signed one and the unsigned one but keeps them both in the same task stack. You may want to consider using singleTask or singleInstance for your Activity if you only want one instance. See the doc on [tasks and back stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Noel regarding the likely cause of Case 2. Without task reparenting or it being set to a launchmode preventing multiple instances of an activity, there is a chance that launching it from Home isn't deemed the same stack as launching it from Eclipse (assuming this to be the case).

In my talent calculator app I have the whole application set allowTaskReparenting=true to ensure nothing is left in other stacks (primarily email as it can email launch urls). I then have my main activity set to launchMode="singleTask" as I only ever want one instance of this to exist no matter what launches it or with whatever intent.

My only other activity is for loading and saving and that has noHistory="true" to make sure it is removed and never returned to. That basically means it only exists while you're in it, and can never return to it.

clearTaskOnLaunch="true" will also ensure only the main Activity remains in the stack when it's launched from Home, but this isn't always the case if you have other ways to get into your activity. If it's only ever launched from Home then set this.

Hope that all helps.

Comment: (1.) allowTaskReparenting=true and launchMode=singleTask : this results in the activity A being shown even when I press the 'home' button when i was in activity B and again click on the  application launcher.
(2.)allowTaskReparenting=true and launchMode=standard : gives the same result as before. 
I would like to state this again that its only the FIRST time that this happens, and when i quit the app by pressing 'back' from activity A, after that the problem disappears

Answer (score 0):

Do you start you application manually or using Eclipse or another IDE? When starting from Intellij IDEA I had exactly the same problems. Then I stopped and ran it manually and behaviour was as expected.

Comment: I am running it using Eclipse.

Comment: Then try stopping it manually through the app managment and run it also manually

Comment: You have an icon in the list of your apps. You can also add this icon to the home screen of your phone. To stop the app you should go to setting and "managing apps" (be memory, may be something similar)

Comment: oh that... I did that already. I uninstalled the app from the 'manage apps' menu and then put the signed apk into sd card, installed the app from there and then tested it

Comment: In your first reply you told that you run it using Eclipse, what does it mean then?

Comment: as mentioned in my question, in Case 1: i use eclipse to run the app in the debug mode on my device and not the emulator.
Case 2: i uninstall the app which was installed by eclipse by going into 'app management' menu and then install the signed APK from sdcard and that version of the app is giving issues. The version i install and run using eclipse gives expected behaviour. 
hope this clears the issue